# Is it always valid to fill an HTML template slot with an element not permitted in the slot's parent?

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

In [the simplest example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots) of `<template>` and `<slot>` on MDN, they use this template:

```
<template id="my-paragraph">
    <p><slot name="my-text">My default text</slot></p>
</template>
```

And later fill the slot like this:

```
<my-paragraph>
  <ul slot="my-text">
    <li>Let's have some different text!</li>
    <li>In a list!</li>
  </ul>
</my-paragraph>
```

This got my attention, because normally, `<ul>` is not allowed inside `<p>`. I went looking for clarification as to whether this was valid or advisable, and haven't found anything addressing it.

*Is* it valid and/or advisable to do this sort of thing? Are there any instances of non-permitted children that are also not permitted when they're only children indirectly via Shadow DOM?

Answer (score 2):

My current best guess is that at least this example is completely fine. The validity issue with `<ul>` inside `<p>` is strictly to do with parsing HTML tags, not document structure; when you do

```
<p><ul></ul></p>
```

directly, the parser implicitly closes the paragraph when you start the list, and the validator's complaint is that the `</p>` doesn't actually have a `<p>` to go with. So the only actual question at play is whether these two constructions are separately fine:

```
<p><slot></slot></p>

<my-paragraph><ul></ul></my-paragraph>
```

…and of course they are. But I'd be interested to hear if there are any other element combinations in this category that *do* cause problems, or if there's spec language I've missed that addresses this situation.

Comment: It's called "implied end tag" in the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags